# Where can I find a list of names for mobile ui components?

Tags: gui-design, mobile, terminology

Long ago when I was just a lad, I sat in my Votech computer programming class and learned Visual Basic.  Visual Basic proved a wonderful primer for learning about UI components and their names.  I learned about the text box, the list box, the dropdown, the combo-box, the button, etc.

Then later in life I learned about html, and ui design patterns such as the bread crumb, the menu, the footer, etc...

Now that mobile websites and apps have emerged, I'm wondering where I can find a list of UI components for mobile apps.  Obviously there's over lap between these and VB / HTML but I've noticed that there are new things here as well, such as menus that scroll horizontally off screen (for example Google on a mobile device), menus the appear behind a page when clicking the three horizontal bars.

What are some good sources to learn the short-names of mobile ui components like these?

Comment: As a UX person I find the set library of components approach overly limiting. It tends to lead to the wrong UI elements used for the wrong solution.

Comment: On an individual level, I'd agree, but on a group level, I've found that component libraries are often a way to get a UX team to EXPAND their options rather than limit it to only what they've personally worked with. So I think it goes both ways (depending on the team)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several 'showcase' pattern libraries out there that can give a nice overview of what's available and trending:

- http://www.mobile-patterns.com/
- http://pttrns.com/
- http://inspired-ui.com/

And many more (if anyone knows others, please add them to this list).

Answer (score 4):

As a basic resource, I personally like the [Designing Mobile Interfaces Book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920013716.do). But in addition, you should always check the vendor specific UI-Guidelines. For example [The Android Design Guide](http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/index.html)

Always keep in mind that some patterns are known under different names. One example: I often hear the term *Spinner* for a loading indicator (mostly from iOS developers), while it's called a *ProgressBar* on android (although it's not a *bar*...). A Spinner on Android is a Drop-down-box. This is also one reason why I like the suggested book - they try to keep it general and call it a *Wait indicator*, and that's pretty much what it is.

Answer (score 4):

A useful source for correct naming conventions of mobile Ui components would possibly be the UI guidelines for the main mobile OS's

[Android User Interface Guidelines](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/index.html)

[iOS Design Resources](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/design/index.html)

[Design library for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windowsphone/develop/fa00461b-abe1-41d1-be87-0b0fe3d3389d%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Also worth taking a look at other guidelines here - http://www.theuxbookmark.com/2010/08/interaction-design/a-monster-list-of-ui-guidelines-style-guides/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Another resource you can take a look at is [UIPatterns.io](http://uipatterns.io). It is a curated list of ui patterns for mobile with interactive examples and explanation.

It is platform and technology agnostic, goes for the basic concepts of designing great UI.